# Java: Class<?> vs. Class

Tags: java, generics

If we are only talking about `Class`, as in `java.lang.Class`, what is the *real* difference between, say

```
Map<Class<?>, Class<?>>
```

and

```
Map<Class, Class>
```

?

For *other* type names like `List` (which is not what this question is about at all), the wildcard makes a difference: you can't put something in a `List<?>` in a type safe manner. Since writing Map gives a compile warning yet I can still do `map.put(Integer.class, String.class)` on it, I was curious to know if it really does matter if `Class` or `Class<?>` gets used.

*Would there be a real point to go through code that has`Map<String, Class>` and replace it with `Map<String, Class<?>`, aside for the compiler warning?*

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 4):

> there seems to be no such thing as "compile vs. does not compile" in the most general Class case.

This is not the case. `Class` and `Class<?>` follow the same restrictions as `List` and `List<?>`, or for any other generic type for that matter.

For example, both of these also compile just as well as your `Class` and `Class<?>` example.

```
List<?> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<?> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<List, List> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(integerList, stringList);
```

and

```
Map<List<?>, List<?>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(integerList, stringList);
```

Comment: This does not compare `Class<?>` vs. `Class`. You're using the `List` type here. I'm asking about the case where `Class` or `Class<?>` is used in the code directly, not some other type.

Comment: I just illustrated that whatever code that compiles or doesn't compile using `Class` and `Class<?>`, gives the exact type of compilation with `List` and `List<?>`, to point out that fact that the generic type `Class<T>` doesn't have any special behavior from any other generic type.

Comment: I have edited my question.